# jquery validation, element name in array format couldn't be set in rules

Tags: jquery

I have an element like

```
<input type="text" id="no_of_days" name="admin_setting[no_of_days]" class="txtbox" maxlength="50" />
```

when I validate like,

```
jQuery("form").validate({

     rules :{   
        admin_setting[no_of_days] : "required"
      },
      messages :{

        admin_setting[no_of_days] : "Please enter the No of Days"

      }

   });
```

It throws the error. Please provide me the way to add the rules inside the validate() function for the element which has the name in array form like "admin_setting[no_of_days]".

I don't want to use .rules() function, as more number of fields to be added in validate() function, instead of calling rules() function for every element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the key, as it's a non-standard key name (i.e. it contains [...]):

```
jQuery("form").validate({

     rules :{   
        'admin_setting[no_of_days]' : "required"
      },
      messages :{

        'admin_setting[no_of_days]' : "Please enter the No of Days"

      }

   });
```